# Show $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {C_n^k{{(k - \frac{n}{2})}^2}} = n{2^{n - 2}}$

Tags: combinatorics

My textbook says it is a simple exercise to derive $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {C_n^k{{(k - \frac{n}{2})}^2}}  = n{2^{n - 2}}$ from $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {C_n^k{x^k}}  = {(1 + x)^n}$ and $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {C_n^k{2^{ - n}}}  = 1$.

I really cannot see how this is "simply" done. Can anyone provide some help? Thank you!

Comment: so i guess $C_n^k$ are binomial coefficents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From
$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {C_n^k{x^k}}  = {(1 + x)^n}$,
differentiate twice
and you can get an
expression for
$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n k{C_n^k{x^k}}
$
and
$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n k^2{C_n^k{x^k}}
$.

Then expand
$(k-\frac{n}{2})^2$
in the sum.

Answer (score 0):

A probabilistic argument. The quantity you are interested in is $2^n$ times the variance of binomial distribution $(n,1/2)$. The latter distribution is a sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli $(1/2)$, so its variance is $n/4$, whence the equality follows.